# Automatically obtain date and time when I type in a cell but in separate columns at google sheets

Tags: datetime, google-sheets

I'm new around here, apologies in advance. I go with my question: I have a google spreadsheet with multiple cells and two sheets. What I am trying to do is that when I type a value in any cell in column 2, the time and date will automatically appear in the adjacent cell. I have gotten this code, which only worked for me on Sheet 1:

```js
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "HOJA 1-HF-SSB" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
      var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
    }
  }
}
```

Then I have managed to simplify it and adapt it to work on both sheets of the document:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
var sheets = ["HOJA 1-HF-SSB", "HOJA 2-FM-DMR"];
if (sheets.indexOf(e.source.getActiveSheet()
    .getName()) === -1 || e.range.columnStart !== 2) return;
e.range.offset(0, 1)
    .setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
}
```

My questions are: Is there a way to get the date and time to go in separate columns? That is, when I fill in column 2, the date is written in column 3 and the time in column 4?

My final goal, apart from separating the date and time, is to determine later (I don't know how to do it) and highlight which values ​​recorded in column 2 are duplicated on the same date, comparing them with the automatic dates in column 3, regardless of the time. Thank you and excuse me, I am a very newbie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (only for column #2)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheets = ["HOJA 1-HF-SSB", "HOJA 2-FM-DMR"];
  if (sheets.indexOf(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()) === -1 || e.range.getColumn() !== 2) return;
  var dateObj = new Date();
  var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
  var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
  var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
  var newdate = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
  e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(newdate).setNumberFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
  e.range.offset(0, 2).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("HH:mm");
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NYxNfoPM6l_PJTPBDxEth2n-T_H0o03FG6C0OMDuJOo/copy

Comment: OK, works for me! Now I have the date and time in different columns (date at 3 and time at 4), is possible to highlight duplicate values in the column 2 but only in the same date (not time)? Sorry if my explanation is hard to understand. I only need to highlight the values in column 2 that are writed in same day (determined with date in column 3). Thanks and sorry! Another option is, when for example B10 and C10 coincides in value and date in any upper row, writes "DUPPED" in another column... I don't know what is better option and easier.

Comment: Select column B, then apply a conditionnal formatting with this formula `=COUNTIF($C:$C,$C1)>1`

Comment: Says "not valid". Select entire B column and apply =COUNTIF($C:$C,$C1)>1. Can you explain this formula? I'm trying to do this: highlight a duplicate when the same text and the same date match. In other words: I need to highlight those values in column B that are repeated each other in the same column and at the same time coincide with the same date in column C...

Comment: I don't know what your region is! I will give you an example, I will also add the search for equality on column B, sorry that was a mistake.

Comment: In Spanish locale, the formula is `=(COUNTIF($C:$C;$C1)>1)*(COUNTIF($B:$B;$B1)>1) > 0` I have added a copy of a spreadsheet in my answer.

Comment: Thanks and sorry another time... Something is wrong or I don't know how to explain you my idea... In any cases, names in column B and dates in column C are matching betwen them and the cell doesn't higlight  properly... I have to apply the formula at all the cells in column B, or in column C too? Or in the heading? Sorry my friend... My apologies.

Comment: select all column B, choose conditional formatting and put formula inside the box